# invalid register with use joi validation

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, joi

I have problem here. when I sign URL register in API tools, I get fail validation. I think this is syntax error but when I check the names of column(in models, database and API tools) is same.

```
auth.controller.js
import { UserModel } from "../models/index.js";
import Bcrypt from 'bcrypt';
import Joi from "joi";
import Jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';
import jwtConfig from "../config/jwt.config.js";

const register = async (req,res) => {
    try {
        const {body} = req;

        const userValidation = Joi.object().keys({
            name:Joi.string().required(),
            nikk: Joi.string().required(),
            contact:Joi.string().required(),
            address: Joi.string().required(),
            job:Joi.string().required(),
            email:Joi.string().required(),
            password:Joi.string().required()
        })

        const {error, value} = userValidation.validate(body)

        if (error){
            return res.status(400)
            .json({
                status:400,
                message: 'sorry, validation fail, check your data again'
            })
        }

        const data = {
            ...value,
            password: await Bcrypt.hash(body.password,10)
        }

        await UserModel.create(data);

        return res.status(201)
        .json({
            status:201,
            message:' register success'
        })
    } 
}
```

Comment: anyone can help?

Comment: can you show `req.body` content?

Comment: i has been done fix this problem, because i didn't put underscored:false in my user.model.js,  thank you for attention

Answer (score 0):

fixed this probelem, because i didn't put underscored:false in my user.model.js

```
import { DataTypes, Model } from "sequelize";

import db from '../config/db.config.js'

export default class UserModel extends Model {}

UserModel.init({
    name:{
        type:DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull:false,
    },
    nikk:{
        type:DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull:false,
    },
    contact:{
        type:DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull:false,
    },
    address:{
        type:DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull:false,
    },
    job:{
        type:DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull:false,
    },
    email:{
        type:DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull:false,
    },
    password:{
        type:DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull:false,
    }
}, {
    sequelize:db,
    freezeTableName:true,
    underscored:false, //solved
    timestamps:false,
    modelName:'user'
})
```